# Asp.net core - Chane image on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap 4 modal for crud operations, When I click on any row in the table it displays the data and the image in modal, and that works for me, but when I want to change the image and upload a new one it didn't display in the current row that I selected, it displayed in the first row.

my js code is :

```
 function clickFile() {
var objfile = document.getElementById("fileAttach");
objfile.click();
return false;
```

}

```
function UploadAttach(input) {
var file = input.files[0];
if (/\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|tiff|gif|ico)$/i.test(file.name.toLowerCase()) === false) {
   alert("الملف المرفق ليس ملف صورة");        
    return false;
}
else {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("imgAttach").src = e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

}

and this is my code in razor view :

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                @if (@item.ProjectPics.Count > 0)
                                                {
                            @if (@item.ProjectPics.FirstOrDefault().Pic != null)
                            {
    <img asp-append-version="true" id="imgAttach" onclick="return clickFile();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="رفع صورة" style="cursor:pointer;" src="@("/images/Project/" + item.ProjectPics.FirstOrDefault().Pic )" width="170" height="170" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
                                <input id="fileAttach" multiple type="file" asp-for="Pics" onchange="UploadAttach(this);" style="display:none;" class="form-input-styled" data-fouc> }
                            else
                            {
    <img asp-append-version="true" id="imgAttach1" src="~/images/noImage.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="رفع صورة" onclick="return clickFile1();" width="170" height="170" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
                                <input id="fileAttach1" multiple type="file" asp-for="Pics" onchange="UploadAttach1(this);" style="display:none;" class="form-input-styled" data-fouc>} }
                        else
                        {
    <img asp-append-version="true" id="imgAttach2" src="~/images/noImage.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="رفع صورة" onclick="return clickFile2();" width="170" height="170" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
                            <input id="fileAttach2" multiple type="file" asp-for="Pics" onchange="UploadAttach2(this);" style="display:none;" class="form-input-styled" data-fouc>}
                                            </div>
```

Comment: just a tip: `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)`

Comment: didn't get it! @Endless

Comment: you can remove the filereader all togheter, you don't need it `document.getElementById("imgAttach").src = URL.createObjectURL(file)` [ObjectURLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: didn't work @Endless

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to change the image and upload a new one it didn't display in the current row that I selected, it displayed in the first row.

I assume that there are more than one `<img>` tags with the same id in current DOM, which might cause this issue.

To fix it, you can try to dynamically get the previous/next sibling instead of getting it by `id`, like below.

```
<img asp-append-version="true" onclick="return clickFile(this);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="رفع صورة" style="cursor:pointer;" src="@("/images/Project/" + item.ProjectPics.FirstOrDefault().Pic )" width="170" height="170" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
<input multiple type="file" asp-for="Pics" onchange="UploadAttach(this);" style="display:none;" class="form-input-styled" data-fouc>
```

JS code

```
function clickFile(img) {
    console.log(img.nextElementSibling);
    var objfile = img.nextElementSibling;
    objfile.click();
    return false;
}


function UploadAttach(input) {
    var file = input.files[0];
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|tiff|gif|ico)$/i.test(file.name.toLowerCase()) === false) {
        alert("الملف المرفق ليس ملف صورة");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var current_row_img = input.previousElementSibling;
                current_row_img.src = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: am getting this error : site.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at clickFile (site.min.js:2)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick  @Fei Han

Comment: `Cannot read property 'click' of null at clickFile` Please check your actual html structure , and try to debug and check `img.nextElementSibling` object.